# Why are there not more auto piloted trains?

Tags: trains, driving

Almost all car companies try to develop  and overachieve each other with better autonomous car driving systems. In planes there are auto pilots for years already, which can fly - human independently - complex routes.

What are the reasons that this doesn't seem to be such a big topic regarding to  trains, even though train systems are run in a very closed, homogeneous and controlled environment, compared to cars on streets or planes in the air?

Comment: I didnt know on which SE network I should have posted this. There are just so many networks ..

Comment: Controlled? In the past ten years, I've been in three train accidents in which the train was hit by a car -- and this is light rail. In contrast, an airplane on autopilot is not going to be anywhere near another plane -- the skies are vast.

Comment: Cost of system development and certification versus cost of human drivers is a big factor. Trade union lobbying is another. Not all trains are in the controlled environments found in the developed world too.

Comment: I think the premises for your question are wrong. Autonomous trains have been around for decades. Several, in particular suburban rail networks or lines are operating autonomously and it *is* a huge topic in rail research and development.

Comment: "autopilot" for aircraft is simply an assistance feature.  (the name may be confusing.)   it's inconceivable a passenger airliners could travel >with no pilots< !! in contrast, there >are< trains (say, those airport shuttles) which operate with absolutely no pilots or crew.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It's also a huge topic in collective bargaining.

Comment: Please commit to the [Area51 Railways and Railroads proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105759/railways-and-railroads).  If this site goes ahead (40% commitment at the moment) this will be an excellent question!

Comment: Pity to see it put on hold.  While not the sort of question the site usually has, it is a "question about … public transport" which is specifically on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Very closed, homogeneous and controlled" while true when you're comparing against planes or cars, is not true in absolute terms.

In a 200 km radius from where I live I have:

- Automated brand-new metro lines. Platforms are separated from tracks with doors that sync with trains' doors.
- Automated but supervised rail and metro network, equipped with [ATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_train_operation) and other safety systems. Still with humans on the very first row to look for obstacles, such as cars, malfunctioning junctions, suicidals, etc.
- Non-automated rail network but with automated, supervised signal control.
- Non-automated rail network with manual signalling.

In essence, what it prevents from automatizing all network is:

- Required investment: To eliminate level crossings and other risks
  like that, to build a reliable signalling infrastructure, and to
  adapt the rolling stock to it.
- The human factor: Many people don't trust automated machines, specially if their life depend on it.
- Jobs: Many people would lose their job, and this usually means less votes for the ruling party. It's easier to build new automated
  lines than adapt existing ones.

Answer (score 5):

There are indeed quite a number of fully automated train lines.

And very many others with highly sophisticated automatic signaling that stops short of full automation.

The main reason for not going further is that the cost is considerable to modify an entire network to enable full automation, while the benefits are minimal:

- Driver's salaries are not so considerable as to make much potential savings.
- The potential safety improvements have largely already been made without full automation.

Comment: The modification-of-existing cost is an excellent point: all the automated trains that come to my mind (ie, the [DLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docklands_Light_Railway)) have been new-build (so they've been able to avoid at-grade crossings, amongst many other important automation-friendly features).

Comment: @MadHatter the exception is the Paris Metro line 1 (and soon line 4) which has been converted from manual to fully-automatic in place. Being a metro line it was already exempt of  grade crossings, but the operation involved the addition of platform doors to prevent people falling on the tracks.

Comment: @jcaron I went from Cambridge to Bordeaux by train late last year, and the new LGV from Paris is *amazing*.  The French, God bless them, do know how to do trains, so it doesn't surprise me that if anyone could convert a metro line *in situ*, RATP could.